# Ethereum wallet recommendation

Tags: wallets, accounts

I'm searching for a software Ethereum wallet + sub-service around it, which is capable of withdrawing to a bank account/PayPal. I would prefer PayPal, but there aren't many of these. Also I need access to a public and secret key so, Coinbase or anything like that is not capable for me. I would also like not to have to verify my identity in order to use it. I believe the cryptocurrency should be anonymous. None of the wallets listed on the website below suit my needs according to the given information. I just need it to receive Ethereum from the mining pool block rewards and then I want to have an option to withdraw the Ethereum into normal fiat currency. I'm also looking for the best ETH miner for my Nvidia RTX 2070, check the question here: [ETH miner recommendation in 2021 (Nvidia RTX 2070)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/94038/eth-miner-recommendation-in-2021-nvidia-rtx-2070).

Wallets list on ethereum.org: https://ethereum.org/en/wallets/find-wallet/

Would anyone here know about an Ethereum wallet that would at least partially meet my requirements? Thank you for the answers in advance.

Comment: I was thinking about MEW: https://www.myetherwallet.com/. What do you think?

Comment: To withdraw from an ETH wallet to fiat currency requires that someone (a counterparty) buys your ETH in the currency you want to withdraw into. To do that you'll need to use an exchange or find someone directly. If you're using an exchange, I think you'll be lucky to find something that lets you bypass the usual anti-money laundering (AML), KYC, and CFT checks.

Comment: Well, then let's say that ID verification is inevitable and not so important for the subject of this question. But at least I don't want to have to verify the ID until I actually use the exchange. Therefore, the ETH wallet itself should not require ID verification in order to generate, manage keys and receive funds from mining. These are still my criteria. If you know of such reliable ETH wallet with low/no fees for receiving and sending funds, don't forget to write them down to the answer. Thank you in advance. Other conditions from the original question still apply.

Comment: I am mean direct fees from the service providing the wallet - not from the Blockchain transactions.

Comment: *I mean | What about Exodus Wallet? https://www.exodus.com/

Comment: I haven't used Exodus so can't really comment. If you just want to create and manage your own private keys, then MyCrypto or MyEtherWallet are good choices that have been around forever (they can be run offline, too). Ledger makes hardware wallets that will do what you want, if you don't mind spending the money to buy one.

Comment: Interesting, honestly, they all seem the same to me. Some of them have a fancier GUI and a few of them also have a mobile app. I really don't know what would be the best choice for me. I do not currently plan to invest in a hardware wallet.