# ETH miner recommendation in 2021 (Nvidia RTX 2070)

Tags: mining, ethminer, nvidia

As you may know, a few days ago I asked which ETH wallet you would recommend. You can find the question here: [Ethereum wallet recommendation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/93978/ethereum-wallet-recommendation)

Unfortunately, I have not received an answer yet.

**Now I would like to ask - which Ethereum miner (pool mining, on Windows) would you recommend for mining especially on RTX 2070?** Do you recommend NiceHash or ClayMore or rather GMiner, Phoenix Mine or any other that comes to your mind? Also could you please explain why? My goal is basically just to try it. As I have an IT background, I have no problems with using the command line interface.

Thank you for the answers in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment, so writing as an answer.  Your question is somewhat opinion-based, so there isn't a perfect answer.  Obviously everyone using a given miner or pool has their reason for thinking that is the best for them, so there is no "right" answer.

I started mining with an RTX 2070 last week.  Was using PhoenixMiner and getting 39.5 MH/s.  I found, like many others, that you have to let the DAG load before overclocking ( [Lots of incorrect shares on one GPU in Phoenix miner](https://www.reddit.com/r/NiceHash/comments/jrqyce/lots_of_incorrect_shares_on_one_gpu_in_phoenix/)).  I have memory overclocked +1447, which is more than I've seen others doing it, but it works and temp stays stable at 67C (laptop).

My longest run has been about 29 hours and then it started throwing incorrect shares.  I have switched to GMiner to see if the same problem occurs.  If it does, it's probably a hardware issue and I'm running it too hard.  GMiner's hashrate is just over 40, so it may be just a bit faster ([Best Ethereum Mining Software for Nvidia and AMD](https://2miners.com/blog/best-ethereum-mining-software-for-nvidia-and-amd/#Testing_NVIDIA_Mining_Software)).   Incidentally, my experience with GMiner is that you also have to allow the DAG to load before overclocking,

I am using the ethermine.org pool.  My advice is to just pick a miner and a pool and start mining.  If there's something you don't like, research the other options or just try something else.  It only takes a few minutes to download and configure a different mining program or redirect it to a different pool, so you won't be spending much time.

**Update:**  PhoenixMiner has a switch that resets overclocking during DAG generation, so you can avoid the issue mentioned above by using something like:

`-mcdag 1 -mclock +1447 -cclock -150`

This should also keep the DAG from getting corrupted if the epoch changes while the miner is running.